# IIS express 7.5 only loading one site even though 2 sites defined?

Tags: iis-express

I have IIS express loaded and running from a command line entry. I am using the default applicationhost.config file (I know it's the correct file as I have changed the 1st site's port a couple of times etc).

The strange thing is, I have two sites defined, and it appears only the first one gets loaded?  I am sure IIS express can load multiple sites right? as long as different ports?

Here is the `<sites>` definition bit from the applicationhost.config file:

```
<sites>
    <site name="BF Local SVN" id="1">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\_CODE SOURCECONTROL\BizzfaceLocalSVN" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6464:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <site name="SquirrelITfreeformBS" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\_CODE SOURCECONTROL\SquirrelITfreeformBS" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6465:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

As you can see, two sites defined, different site ID's and different ports?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide the command line you're using to launch IIS Express?

Comment: Hi Joshua, sorry for the delay.. I was literally running "iisexpress" at the command line.. from what I understood, it would load the default applicationhost.config and process.

Actually the answer below as fixed it.. I didn't realise you could do that.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When you run iisexpress.exe from command line (without any command line arguments), it starts the first site given in default applicationhost.config file (%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config).

To start multiple sites, use /apppool switch as shown below;

```
iisexpress.exe /apppool:Clr4IntegratedAppPool
```

Above command would start all the applications that are using 'Clr4IntegratedAppPool' app pool.

Comment: Cool, thank you! had no idea you could do that - so saved me heaps of time! thanks!

Comment: You can also create a shortcut and set it to run "minimized" if you want to hide the command window. See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-a-shortcut-to-start-task-manager-in-minimized-mode/ for an example.

Comment: Great tip here. Couldn't find it anywhere else. Now, I just need to find out how to keep Visual Studio from stuffing all of my projects into the same apppool name. Right now, they're all in Clr4IntegratedAppPool. I need a separate apppool for each solution so that I can start multiple servers for each with a single command. Anyone know how to do that?